# Rails 4 returning rows with no through: relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to find a list of Surveys that the user *hasn't* taken

I have a UserAnswer model which is my has many through relationship to survey.

To find a list of surveys the user has taken I can simply write:

```
current_user.surveys
```

How can I get a list of Surveys the user hasn't taken?

I'm guessing I'm looking for something like

```
Surveys.where(!UserAnswer.survey_id: [current_user.surveys.ids])
```

Answer (score 0):

So close!

```
Surveys.where.not(survey_id: [current_user.surveys.ids])
```

At least, it's the most direct path to valid code from yours. As of resulting SQL, I think there is a more performant way using joins. I'm still not perfect with joins, so I can't give any advice.